# Finding maximus array

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

I don't understand how this code find the rectangle or square where the sum of all integers are maximum, specially how the adding and subtracting working inside the for loop

if this approach or algorithm has a name, plz let me know
the code is-

```
#include <iostream>
#include <limits.h>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
int n=3,a[3][3]={-1,1,2,0,3,4,0,-1,0};
int i,j,k,l;

for(i=0; i<n; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<n; j++)
        {
            if(i>0) a[i][j]+=a[i-1][j];
            if(j>0) a[i][j]+=a[i][j-1];
            if(i>0&&j>0) a[i][j]-=a[i-1][j-1];
        }
    }

int ans=INT_MIN;
for(i=0; i<n; i++)
{
    for(j=0; j<n; j++)
    {
        for(k=i; k<n; k++)
        {
            for(l=j; l<n; l++)
            {
                int temp=a[k][l];
                if(i>0) temp-=a[i-1][j];
                if(j>0) temp-=a[i][j-1];
                if(i>0 && j>0) temp+=a[i-1][j-1];
                if(temp>ans) ans=temp;
            }
        }
    }
}
cout<<ans;
return 0;

}
```

Thanks

Comment: please be more specific. what is your questions? you should not ask questions like: "here is my code, what is it doing?".

Comment: Look at [Summed_area_table](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Summed_area_table).

Comment: i hope you understand a-=b => a=a-b